# How do I set up mopub ad service

Tags: mopub

I have tried creating an app via mobpub and imported the ad unit into game maker and the ad says welcome to mopub and no ad shows actually shows.

What is the exact step by step to create a mopub ad for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to activate the ad networks that you wish to target.

Please follow the guides here that outline the steps on how to get started.  Curious which mobile platform you are on?

First Setup your Ad Network:
http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/785343

Then Create and Manage a Segment (Ad Network):
http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/1281488-create-and-manage-a-segment-ad-networks-

Along with creating orders/line items:  http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/784995-creating-orders-line-items

Please review the guide on how to integrate with Third Party Ad-Networks:
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks

Hope this helps!

Best,
WiLL

Comment: Ok I have did everything but now I think I have to create a creative because the default is the mopub one which is just a demo. What do I put in the creative to show ads from the ad service I chose Millennia Media?

Comment: You would need to first register with Millennia and enter their credentials within MoPub's UI.  From there you would need to create line items to target the ad network